# MultiResolution in Firemonkey Mobile Application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, timage, firemonkey-fm3

Is there any demo available that shows how multi-resolution images should be handled in a mobile application with button images, splash screen and a background for example? I'm trying to make an application that looks nice on many resolution but i have problems doing it.

For example, if i load my application in a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 7, it will automatically load any image i have at the ratio of 1.0, but if i load my application in a samsung galaxy s4 then it will load the image of 1.5 ratio. Now... if i use an image of 480x800 in ratio 1 it's kinda small for the Galaxy Tab 2.0's screen and if i load the app again in a mobile with a smaller screen that will use too the ratio 1.0 the image size is ok.

Since i can't appoint two different resolution images to one specific ratio how am i supposed to use the MultiResolution property of TImage correctly?

Comment: According to the documentation on [Using Multi-Resolution Bitmaps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Multi-Resolution_Bitmaps), it looks like you're supposed to use the [MultiResBitmap Editor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/MultiResBitmap_Editor)

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I think you should add that as an answer. (Especially if you can show how a MRB is placed on a form or linked to, say, a button. I found the documentation extensive but unclear.)

Comment: @DavidM, I hope someone else will provide an answer. I don't have XE5, so I can't do anything more than quote the docs.

Comment: Of course i checked these i am aware of their existence but thing is that there is nothing on the internet on how to use them properly. Two mobile devices that use the same ratio might have a big difference in the size of the screen so they need images of different resolution. I'm curious about how to organize all in order to have a nice GUI in most devices

Comment: @Mitsoloth, ratio isn't considered. It's density (scale).